# Google app engine: query that return entity ID using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

how do I return the entity ID using python in GAE?

Assuming I have following

```
class Names(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You retrieve the entity, e.g. with a [query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_Entities_Using_a_Query), then you call `.key().id()` on that entity (will be `None` if the entity has no numeric id; see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_app) for other info you can retrieve from a `Key` object).

Comment: You can also SELECT ____key____ FROM ... using GQL, which is a quick way to get the key without the overhead of loading the full entity.

Comment: Could you mind write the complete coding as I really new to datastore

Answer (score 5):

The question has long been answered.
(I am adding some full examples hopefully while not stepping on any toes...)

**Getting an entity using a query; just getting the keys is [faster and uses less CPU than retrieving the full entity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries?csw=1#Python_Keys_only_queries):**

```
query = Names.all(keys_only=True)
names = query.get() # this is a shorter equivalent to `query.fetch(limit=1)`
names.id()
```

**From a template:**

```
{{ names.id }}
```

**GQL alternative, as suggested in a comment:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Names")
names = query.get()
names.id()
```